# How to get records of uids where skill='Python' and skill = 'Javascript'

Tags: mysql

So basically I need to get people where their skill = 'Python' and skill='Javascript' however I am getting an empty set when I run this query:

```sql
SELECT uid 
FROM personal_hard_skills 
WHERE 
(skill='Python' AND level >) 
AND skill='Javascript';
```

I searched the internet and people were suggesting using a form of an intersection query. Would that work with different from the same table?

So for context if I run the query to get everything in this table:

```
mysql> SELECT uid FROM personal_hard_skills;
+----+-------+-----------------+------------+-------+---------------------+
| id | uid   | skill           | skill_code | level | timestamp           |
+----+-------+-----------------+------------+-------+---------------------+
| 25 | Dave  | Javascript      |          1 |  3.00 | 2019-07-18 19:50:19 |
| 26 | Dave  | Python          |          3 |  5.00 | 2019-07-18 19:50:19 |
| 27 | John  | Javascript      |          1 |  1.00 | 2019-07-18 19:51:23 |
| 28 | John  | Python          |          3 |  3.45 | 2019-07-18 19:51:23 |
| 29 | John  | Adobe Photoshop |          8 |  4.20 | 2019-07-18 19:51:23 |
| 30 | John  | HTML            |         64 |  2.50 | 2019-07-18 19:51:24 |
| 31 | John  | CSS             |         49 |  0.82 | 2019-07-18 19:51:24 |
| 35 | Helen | Javascript      |          1 |  4.35 | 2019-07-18 19:51:52 |
| 36 | Helen | Python          |          3 |  4.99 | 2019-07-18 19:51:52 |
| 37 | Helen | CSS             |         49 |  3.50 | 2019-07-18 19:51:52 |
+----+-------+-----------------+------------+-------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

But when I run this query:

```
mysql> SELECT uid FROM personal_hard_skills WHERE skill='Python' AND skill='Javascript';
Empty set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: A single skill can never be *both* Python and JavaScript at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use aggregation:

```
SELECT uid 
FROM personal_hard_skills 
WHERE skill IN ('Python','Javascript')
GROUP BY uid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skill) = 2;
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT uid
FROM personal_hard_skills 
WHERE (skill = 'Python' AND level >= 4.0) OR (skill = 'JavaScript' AND level >= 2.0)
GROUP BY uid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skill) = 2;
```

Comment: What if I also wanted to also filter by level. Like where for python I want a level 4 or above and javascript 2 or above?

Comment: @Gowtham Sundar I included this new criteria to my answer. If it's part of the question, please add it there.

Answer (score 0):

Combining feedback from the original post and comments, this should work:

```sql
SELECT uid
  FROM personal_hard_skills
  WHERE (skill = 'Python' AND level >= 4.0)
  OR (skill = 'JavaScript' AND level >= 2.0);
```

The issue in the original post was `AND`-- no `personal_hard_skills` can have a skill of 'Python' *and* 'JavaScript'.